# how to include only certain packages in jar during gradle build

Tags: java, build, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with following package structure
src/com/a1
src/com/a2
src/com/a3
src/com/a4

I have written a gradle script to build the jar, which contains compiled java files of all the packages. I want only "a2" and "a4" packages inside jar.
**However: classes in a2 and a4 are referring to the classes present in the "a1" and "a3"**

Answer (score 4):

1. Multi-project build

You actually want to split your project into a **multi-project**. Including only particular packages from a project is error-prone. Gradle has a great documentation on multi-project builds:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

2. exclude in Jar task

If you still want to exclude a1 and a3 from the JAR, you can try something like this:

```
task myJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.main.output
  exclude 'a1/**'
  exclude 'a3/**'
}
```

Check the documentation to the Jar task for details:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

However, I do not recommend this. We did this with Ant by specifying excludes and includes, and that has always been a source of bugs, causing NoClassDefFoundError.